# Listing buckets Amazon s3 via PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk

I am trying to learn AWS SDK v3. I have been following the documentation but I get a white screen error.

I have credentials in a **~/.aws/credentials file**, used Composer to install `"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.14"`

I am trying to list the buckets using the following:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$bucket = 'vcch-temp';

// S3
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'profile' => 'vcch2',   
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => 'latest'
]);

$result = $s3->listBuckets(array());
foreach ($result['Buckets'] as $bucket) {
    echo $bucket['Name'], PHP_EOL;
}
echo 'done';
```

So far I have tried multiple examples for both elastictranscoder and s3 I get a white screen everytime.

The example above gets as far as
`$result = $s3->listBuckets(array());` then fails.

links to page example

works e.g. comment out `$result = $s3->listBuckets(array());`
https://alfa.pcsmarts.biz/s3/mytest2.php

fails https://alfa.pcsmarts.biz/s3/mytest.php

Comment: The AWS S3 credentials you are using does have the permission for bucket Listing??? If not, then you will have to give permission for bucket listing to the user.

Comment: You get a white screen, not a screen that says "done"? That means you were receiving a server error that wasn't being displayed on the webpage.